# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'body' was called on null

Tags: flutter, api, post, get, nosuchmethoderror

**I'm trying to fetch data from an api by passing bearer token but it is throwing this exception. Here's my code below :**

This is my **afterLoginResponse.dart** class -

```
 class AfterLoginResponse {
    LoginData? data;
    bool? operator;
    bool? success;

 AfterLoginResponse({
   required this.operator,
   required this.success,
   required this.data,
});

AfterLoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   operator = json['operator'];
  success = json['success'];
  data = LoginData.fromJson(json["data"]);
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
  "operator": operator,
  "success": success,
  "data": data!.toJson(),
 };
}
```

Below is my **loginData.dart** class ->

```
class LoginData {
  String? name;
 String? ext;
 String? dName;
 String? password;

LoginData({
  required this.name,
  required this.ext,
  required this.dName,
  required this.password,
});

factory LoginData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
 return LoginData(
    name: json['name'],
    ext: json['ext'],
    dName: json['d_Name'],
    password : json['password'],
   );
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
  data['name'] = name;
  data['ext'] = ext;
  data['d_Name'] = dName;
  data['password'] = password;
  return data;
 }
}
```

This is my **apiService.dart** class -

```
class ApiService{
 String? token;
 var response1;
 var response2;

Future<LoginResponseData> loginApiCall(Map<String, dynamic> param) async{
  var url = Uri.parse(ApiUrls.login_url);
  response1 =  await http.post(url, body: param);
  final data = jsonDecode(response1.body);
  token = LoginResponseData.fromJson(json.decode(response1.body)).token;
    return LoginResponseData(user: data['user'], token: 
        data['token'],error:data['error']);
  }

Future<AfterLoginResponse> postLoginApiCall() async{
  var afterLoginUrl = Uri.parse(ApiUrls.postLogin_url);
  response2 = await http.get(afterLoginUrl , headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 
  ${LoginResponseData.fromJson(json.decode(response1.body)).token}'
 });

  if(response2.statusCode == 200){
    var data =  jsonDecode(response2.body);
    return AfterLoginResponse.fromJson(data);
   }else{
   throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
 }
}
```

Here is my **UI** -

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   String email, password;

 HomePage({Key? key, required this.email, required this.password})
     : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
  }

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  late Future<AfterLoginResponse> afterLoginResponse;

  final apiService = ApiService();

  callPostLoginApi(){
    return FutureBuilder<AfterLoginResponse>(
     future: afterLoginResponse,
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
         return Text(snapshot.data!);
         print(snapshot.data);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
      }

      // By default, show a loading spinner.
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
     },
   );
  }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: const Text('Home page'),
       centerTitle: true,
     ),
     body: Center(
       child: Column(
         children: [
           ElevatedButton(
             onPressed: callPostLoginApi,
               child: const Text('Click me'))
          ],
        ),
      )
   );
 }
```

The above code is throwing following exception -
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'body' was called on null.
Receiver: null
E/flutter (28599): Tried calling: body
E/flutter (28599): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
.
.
.

Comment: print response of the api before you try to convert it to model.

Comment: I have already  printed in my code, here i have removed that line.

Answer (score 0):

in the postLoginApiCall you are calling body with response1 variable which is at that very time null that is causing the issue change that to response2 like this:

```
Future<AfterLoginResponse> postLoginApiCall() async{
  var afterLoginUrl = Uri.parse(ApiUrls.postLogin_url);
  response2 = await http.get(afterLoginUrl , headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 
  ${LoginResponseData.fromJson(json.decode(response2.body)).token}'
 });

  if(response2.statusCode == 200){
    var data =  jsonDecode(response2.body);
    return AfterLoginResponse.fromJson(data);
   }else{
   throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: No, actually from response1 variable I'm getting token value, that i have to pass to the next api.

Comment: first of all you haven't assigned any value to the late variable afterLoginResponse. and if you want to get the toke from the response1 variable then you have to first call loginApiCall method on ApiService and then postLoginApiCall on the same object.

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working. still providing the same error.

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: and are you getting the same error?

Comment: yes still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251727/discussion-between-munsif-ali-and-anjali).

Comment: I got the output, by making response variable final, and rather than declaring response variable differently, I have to make it final in the respected methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `postLoginApiCall` after getting response from the `loginApiCall`

```
Future<LoginResponseData> loginApiCall(Map<String, dynamic> param) async{
  ...
}

Future<AfterLoginResponse> postLoginApiCall() async{
   ...
}

loginApiCall().then((value) => postLoginApiCall());  // like this
```